# Getting "nbsp" on InvalidPluginExecutionException

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, on-premises-instances

Hi when i'm calling InvalidPluginExecutionException in a plugin i'm getting the '&nbsp' instead of spaces, this is only happening in the Connection entity.
This is dynamics on-prem (9.0.26.5)

This is the line of code:

```cs
throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Can't connect 2 Structures or 2 Contacts !\n");
```

This is the result:

> Can't&nbsp;connect&nbsp;2&nbsp;Structures&nbsp;or&nbsp;2&nbsp;Contacts&nbsp;!
> If you contact support, please provide the technical details.

[image: Image of the error message]

Comment: should have a semicolon? `&nbsp;`

Comment: I only removed the semicolon to represent the error(you can check the image to have a better look), thanks for noticing, already added that to the description

Comment: Looks like you entered non breaking spaces (ASCII 160) instead of spaces (ASCII 32).